# Fold with Kotlin in a property of a data class model in an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, fold

I'm not sure the title is clarifying enough, so I'll explain here:
I have four models:

This model is the one I use for parsing the JSON from a file

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Account(
    val account: String,
    val balance: String,
    val transactions: List<Transaction>
)
```

This `Account` has a list of `Transactions`:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Transaction(
    val id: String,
    val amount: String,
    val description: String,
    val otherAccount: String,
    val date: String
)
```

For the UI layer, I have some equivalent models:

```
data class AccountEntity(
    val account: String,
    val balance: String,
    val transactions: List<TransactionEntity>
)
```

and

```
data class TransactionEntity(
    var amount: BigDecimal,
    var balanceBefore: BigDecimal,
    var balanceAfter: BigDecimal,
    val description: String,
    val otherAccount: String,
    val date: Date
)
```

The tricky thing I want to do is, that an `Account` has a `balance` and I need to show in every `TransactionData` the `balanceBefore` and the `balanceAfter` which are respectively, the balance of the account BEFORE this transaction was made, and the balance of the account AFTER this transaction was made.

For me this is a bit tricky not only to understand but also to implement.
I thought of maybe implementing some sort of `fold` operation in every transaction, but I'm not sure how to apply it only in the `balanceBefore` and the `balanceAfter` properties.

Any other idea? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Where did u do these transactions? using Room?

Comment: no, I'm not using DB or anything. With `Transaction` I mean a bank transaction, it's a banking app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's some sort of `reduce/fold` function that also allows you to `map` your `Transaction` objects.

What this function do is to track the current balance in an accumulator and transform each `Transaction` object:

```
inline fun <R> List<Transaction>.map(
    initial: Int,
    transform: (transaction: Transaction, beforeBalance: Int, afterBalance: Int) -> R
): List<R> {
    var accumulator = initial
    val destination = ArrayList<R>()

    for (transaction in this) {
        val after = accumulator - transaction.amount
        destination.add(transform(transaction, accumulator, after))
        accumulator = after
    }
    return destination
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
account.transactions.map(account.balance, {t, b, a-> TransactionEntity(...)})
```

To be more generic and functional, you can move this line `accumulator - transaction.amount` to the function parameter as a fold input, and call the function foldMap or whatever which reduce your current transaction and also map it.

Comment: thanks a lot man, this is really the answer I was looking for!